# Generic Function To extract Decimal part of a float without Floor()

Tags: c

I want to split the float number to two separate part as real and non real part.
For example: if `x = 45.678`, then my function have to give `real= 45` and `non_real=678`. I have tried the following logic.

```
split ( float x, unsigned int *real, unsigned int *non_real)
{
   *real = x;
   *non_real = ((int)(x*N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION)%N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION);
    printf ("Real = %d , Non_Real = %d\n", *real, *non_real);
}
```

where `N_DECIMAL_POINTS_PRECISION = 10000`. It would give decimal part till 4 digits, not after.

It works only for specific set of decimal point precision. The code is not generic, it has to work for all floating numbers also like `9.565784` and `45.6875322` and so on. So if anyone could help me on this, it would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please chose the poison? C or C++?

Comment: @EdHeal seems that there's no C++ code in the snippet.

Comment: you could convert to string and split according to dot. there's a problem in your question: the decimal part is theorically infinite, so that could not fit in an integer, and it could return 68799 like 68799000001 depending on the precision...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `floor()` to find the integer part, and then subtract the integer part from the original value to find the fractional part.

Note: The problem you're most likely having is that some numbers are too large for the integer part to fit in the range of an `int`.

--Added--

If and only if you are able to assume that an `unsigned int` is larger than the floating point representation's significand (e.g. 32-bit `unsigned int` and IEEE standard single-precision floating point with only 23 fractional bits, where "32 < 23" is true); then a number that is too large for an `unsigned int` can't have any fractional bits. This leads to a solution like:

```
if(x > UINT_MAX) {
    integer_part = x;
    fractional_part = 0;
} else {
    integer_part = (int)x;
    fractional_part = x - integer_part;
}
```

Comment: Brendan I cannot use any libraries.

Comment: @NitinNagaraj: Then I'd recommend asking a new question titled "How to implement `floor()` (using inline assembly or something)". ;-)

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this? without floor().

Comment: Why cannot use a library?

Comment: @NitinNagaraj: Yes; using other library functions (e.g. `ceil()`), or writing non-portable code (inline assembly and/or code that relies on the exact formats of integer and floating point types), or being excessively complex and slow and still losing accuracy.

Comment: Can you please help me in writing that code?

Comment: @NitinNagaraj: Added a "potentially least worst" alternative (that isn't portable and will break if `unsigned int` happens to be a perfectly legal 16-bit type).

Comment: @NitinNagaraj: Note that you could use a different integer type (`unsigned long long`); and that I've assumed `x` is not negative, and that `integer_part` has to be `float` or `double` because of the "too large to fit in an integer type" problem.

Comment: @Brendan: Got it! But one more thing how do you access that fraction part as an integer? The output should be _italic_ **bold** `code`fraction part = 94567 not 0.94567. I think th output from above code would be 0.94567

Comment: @NitinNagaraj: That part is easy - just multiply by a power of ten and convert (cast) to integer. As long as your power of 10 fits in an integer, the result will fit

Comment: @Brendan: Is it possible without pow() function??i know its irritating, but i cannot use any libraries.

Comment: @Brendan: I have solved it, first count number of decimal parts and take power of ten. Now API is working perfectly fine. Thanks